# Gradle build failure with Task 'cI' is ambiguous error for Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to build my spring boot project using "gradle cI id" command. Unfortunately, I'm getting below error which I don't really understand.BTW, "gradle clean build" worked fine. Can someone help me to understand what it really means ?

`Task 'cI' is ambiguous in root project 'life'. Candidates are: 'compileJava', 'compileTestJava'.`

Can someone help me to understand what does this error really means ?

I'm using Java 17, Gradle 8.1.1 .My build.gradle looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.nifty'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: What is cI id? I never heard of that

Answer (score 0):

Gradle allows executing task based using an abbreviated task name: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:name_abbreviation

`./gradlew clean build` works because these are explicit tasks that are contributed to your project by the Gradle plugins you have applied.

`./gradlew cI id` fails because there does not exist a task nor task abbreviation named of either.